# select2 multi select with minimum character bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 for some time now, but I just started using multi selects.
Since the beginning I am having the same issue.

Whenever I make a multiselect dropdown with the requirement of minimum 1 character, it tells me "Please enter 1 or more characters", fine right?

Well when I click somewhere else in my page this popup persists.

How to remove this issue?

```
$("#e1").select2({ 
     minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jeanpaul1994/3tfcm83n/1/

**EDIT**

My multi select.
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Visit.ExtraHosts, new List(), null, new { @class = "form-control select2-customselector", @multiple = "multiple" })

My Ajax call.

```
$('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.Visit.EmployeeId), #@Html.IdFor(model => model.Visit.ExtraHosts)').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetHostsViaAJAX", "Visitors")',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        searchTerm: params.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return { results: data };
                }
            },
            placeholder: "@IAMMVCResources.SelectAHost",
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            allowClear: true
        });
```

Comment: Hey there, just wondering if my answer below has solved your problem.

Comment: Hi @jacobheater i haven't had the time to test it yet, since the time being here now is 8 am, I will test this in a few minutes and I will tell you, it looks promising!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a lot about this particular plugin, but after using the fiddle that you posted, I have come up with a fix. I have extended the jQuery function by adding an additional method to fix select2. The code can be found below, and the [fiddle has been updated](http://jsfiddle.net/3tfcm83n/6/).

```
/******************************************************
*******************************************************
Fixes select2.js issues with multi-select <select> elements.
*******************************************************
*******************************************************/
(function($) {
    //Make sure that the html mouseup event listener is not added more than once.
  var isFixed = false;
  $.fixSelect2 = function() {
    if (!isFixed) {
        //Set is fixed to true to prevent event listener from being added more than once.
      isFixed = true;
      $('html').mouseup(function(e) {
        //The target of the mouseup event.
        var target = $(e.target);
        var classList = null;
        var isSelect2 = false;
        var name = "";
        var hideSelect2 = function() {
          $('.select2-dropdown-open').removeClass('select2-dropdown-open');
          $('.select2-drop').hide();
        };
        //If the target is not the html element, proceed.
        if (!target.is(this)) {
            //Get the class of the target element, if applicable.
          classList = target.attr('class');
          //If the element has class(es), parse them.
          if (classList !== "") {
            classList = classList.split(' ');
            for (var i = 0, len = classList.length; i < len; i++) {
              name = classList[i];
              //If current class name contains "select2" in the string
              //then we can assume the element is a select2 element
              //and no further processing is necessary.
              if (name.indexOf('select2') > -1) {
                isSelect2 = true;
                break;
              }
            }
          }
          //Only if the target of the mouseup event is not a select2 element
          //We should hide the select2 components.
          if (!isSelect2) {
            hideSelect2();
          }
        } else {
            //If the event target is the html element itself, then this is outside of the current
          //select2 context and we know that the target is not a select2 element, so we should
          //proceed to hide the select2 elements.
          hideSelect2();
        }
      });
    }
    //Return the jQuery instance for chaining.
    return this;
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This works on most places, but something is different between my version and this one,

I use Select2 version 4.0.0, I also use a bootstrap plugin version, but this is only css.

Comment: @JpHouten Just so I understand, you're saying that the fix doesn't work 100% of the time? If that is the case, can you tell me how it's not behaving as expected so I can modify the code? I'd like to get you a resolution.

Comment: It is working on the jsfiddle, but it is not working in my application, maybe I am implementing it in the wrong way (tested it in multiple places, my general.js which gets included last on every page, within the page as very last piece of code, and as first.). The problem persist in the same way it did before in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Would you mind providing a code sample of how you're actually using it in your application? @JpHouten

Comment: @JpHouten Thanks! I see the edits, but I don't see where you're making the $.fixSelect2() call. If you don't invoke the $.fixSelect2 method, it won't fix the issue you're having in select2. Since I can't invoke your AJAX call in a fiddle, I have created a segment of commented code. Please see the fiddle I have created for an example. https://jsfiddle.net/JacobHeater/kyw2z1h8/

Comment: I noticed that I am only encoutering this issue in 1 page, the 4  other pages are working without a problem. (before all 5 pages had this problem) Your fix does work! But for some reason not on this particular page.

Comment: @JpHouten this particular page is the one with the AJAX implementation specifically?

Comment: They all have the same implementation of AJAX, they are actually copies of eachother, with only 2 modifications (the ID and the url).
They are copies because it must be possible to change the options. Although I am thinking about making a functions that generates the right javascript for me, so that I am sure that .select2 is exactly the same everywhere.

Comment: Is this a public facing site that I might be able to help you debug on my side? If not, is it possible to share your screen with me or see it via some other means?

Comment: unfortunatly It is not public and I am not allowed to share full source codes or do teamviewer controlled help. I am trying to reproduce my code on jsfiddle, but I cannot seem to get it into the same scenario, it seems that my local code is freaking with select2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98719/discussion-between-jacob-heater-and-jp-houten).